# How to prove the two integrals are equal $?$

Tags: integration

For  a  harmonic  complex  valued  function  $u(z)$ ,the  differential   $-{{\partial u}\over {\partial y}}dx + {{\partial u}\over {\partial x}}dy $  $\ \ $ is  closed .  Then  by Green's Theorem  and  *harmonicity  of  $u$*  we  have $$\int_{|z-z_0|=r} -{{\partial u}\over {\partial y}}dx + {{\partial u}\over {\partial x}}dy\ =0\ $$  where  the  circle  $|z-z_0|=r$  is  a  smooth  closed  curve.

Parametrizing  the  circle  as
$$z(\theta )=(x(\theta),y(\theta));\\
x(\theta)=x_0+r \cos{\theta} \\
y(\theta)=y_0+r \sin{\theta}$$
where $ z_0=(x_0,y_0)$, I have 
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\left[{{\partial u}\over {\partial x}}\cos{\theta} +{{\partial u}\over {\partial y}}\sin{\theta} \right] \, d\theta = 0 $$
 *[ I  have  evaluated  only $dx$  and  $dy$    but  not  $\partial x$ or  $\partial y$  so  I'm  not  sure  if  this  is  correct  at  all]*
 Now  I  need  this above  equation   to  imply  that  $${{\partial}\over {\partial r}}\int_0^{2\pi} u(z_0+re^{i \theta}) \, d\theta  = 0.$$

How  do  I  do  this?

**Clarifying  my  question  more  :**  We  have  $$x(\theta)=x_0+r \cos\theta\\y(\theta)=y_0+r \sin\theta$$
Then differentiating  we  have  $$dx=-r\sin\theta \\dy=r\cos\theta $$
 and  substitute  them  in  the  equation . Could  we  find , in  similar manner , $$\delta x \ \ and\ \ \delta y$$ $?$
and  put  them  as  the  denominator  of  ${\delta u}\over {\delta x}$ and ${\delta u}\over {\delta y}$ $?$  Or   is using  *chain rule*   the  only  possibility $?$

I  hope  this  time  I have  managed  to  convey  my  query $?$

Comment: Argue that you can differentiate under the integral?